# How can I render a _form file from a different controller without having conflicting form_for's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have 2 models, Box.rb and Toy.rb. Rails gives me pages and methods to create new toys and boxes independently. However, I would like to ensure/provide the ability to create a box's first toy *when creating a box for the first time*.

In line with DRY, I wanted to simply put `<%= render "Toy/form" %>` inside the `_form.html.erb` file that is made for `Box`.

The problem is that Toy's `_form` file contains, well, a `form_for` method for obvious reasons. It's a problem for what I am trying to do because I will end up with 1 form nested in the other, while all I really want is to get the Toy fields while keeping to DRY…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` along with `fields_for`.Assuming your associations are like this

```
#box.rb
Class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :toys
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :toys
end

#toy.rb
Class Toy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
end


#box_controller.rb

def new
 @box = Box.new
 @toy = @box.toys.build
end

def create
  @box = Box.new(box_params)
  if @box.save
    -----
  else
    -----
  end
end

private

def box_params
  params.require(:box).permit(:box_attribute_1,:box_attribute_2,:more_box_attributes, toys_attributes: [:toy_attribute_1,:more_toy_attributes])
end
```

In your `box/form`,you can do like this

```
  <%= form_for(@box) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :box_attribute_1 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :box_attribute_1 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :box_attribute_2 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :box_attribute_2 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :box_attribute_3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :box_attribute_3 %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for @toy do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'toys/form', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Hmm, a follow-up Q...how would you do the `create`? Would passing `box_params` to `Box.new()` suffice? Do I need to say `Box.new(box_params)` and `Toy.new(toys_attributes)`?

Comment: @Jo.P I updated the `create` method for you.If you provide the `attributes` for `box` and `toy`,i will modify the `box_params` too :)